# How can i manipulate an object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

This is on my PHP:

```
if(whatever)
{
 echo("GOOD"
}
else
{
    $result['msg'] = "Mesagge for AngularJS";
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

And this is what I getting for angular:

```
.service('upload', ["$http", "$q", "$location", function ($http, $q, $location, $scope)
{
    this.uploadFile = function(file, idPunto)
    {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("name", idPunto);
        formData.append("file", file);
        return $http.post("Uploads/server.php", formData, {
            headers: {
                "Content-type": undefined
            },
      params: {id: idPunto},
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        })
        .then(function successCallback(res)
        {
            //Here I need to comparate the object result from PHP
            if(res.data == 'message from PHP')
            {
                $location.url("/controlPanel");
            }
            else
            {
              console.log("not is equal");
            }                
            deferred.resolve(res);
        }
        ,function errorCallback(msg, code)
        {
            deferred.reject(msg);
        })
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}])
```

Result: **Object { msg: "Mesagge for AngularJS" }** 
**on the function (res)**

So, I need to comparate the object result

I can't use ***$scope***, because at service from angular can't used whit it.

```
//Example of that.
$scope.tableRepeat= dataImages.data;
```

Comment: Which object are you trying to mutate? Where is it located?

Comment: Please close your parentheses in your code... two such syntax errors.

Comment: Also include more code. It would be helpful to know what function is wrapping your '//LITTLE EXAMPLE!' if statement, and also the code where you are invoking this function.

Comment: Im trying to comparate the object that its returned from php,on function successCallback(res). @bazzells

Comment: and I've updated my complete function @trincot

Comment: Ok, and you're looking to mutate `res`, right? Where do you want the mutated version of `res` to be accessible? In the controller that is loaded when navigating to: `"/controlPanel"`?

Comment: No, in PHP i have a conditional, it evaluates if is an image/* and his extension, else so show us the message on console log(Object { msg: "Isnt a correct file" }). After I need to comparate the object result(I don't know how, i'm lost) and take the way for an error 405, and show to the user, and say what's the possible mistake! For give me if i couldnt express what i want

Comment: I see. If I understand correctly, you would want to compare `res.data.msg`, rather than just `res.data`, in your JS if/else inside `successCallback`

Comment: exactly! Thank you, sometimes i'm so .... but, the solution is  [res.data.msg] @bazzells, post the solution and I'll give you the qualification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close, just had to unpack the response object a bit more.

In your `successCallback`, use `res.data.msg` for your evaluation, rather than just `res.data`.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear , wich object do you want to compare ??

I made this code with jquery to do what I think you are searching for:

**page.php:**

```
<?php 
$result['msg'] = "Mesagge for AngularJS";
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url:'page.php',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data) {
                if(data.msg =="Mesagge for AngularJS")
                {
                    alert(data.msg);
                }else{
                    alert("no data found!");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope that will help you.